# With a 3-dimensional python vector, how do I avoid "only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" arising from the syntax of a for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My (actual) code is finding dimensional averages of east-west wind (i.e., the average windspeed averaged from every longitude across a single latitude), but I'm not around it right now so I've reproduced it below. Essentially, the problem comes from the following snippet of code:

```
time = []
lat = range(-90, 90)
lon = range(0, 180)
u10m = np.random.randint(-10, 20, (len(time),len(lat),len(lon)))
psum = 0
u_zavg = np.zeros(len(lat))
print(time)
for i in range(len(lat)):
  for j in range(len(lon)):
    psum += u10m[:,i,j]
  u_zavg[i] = psum/len(lon)
  psum = 0
```

with the error being returned at

```
u_zavg[i] = psum/len(lon).
```

I'm almost certain it's due to the time dimension of my variable. Is there any way around it? I've tried a couple things like adding a `l = sum(k, axis = 0)` and then using `l` in the place of `psum` in the `i` loop but that didn't really help.

`psum` is supposed to be the sum of all the values at every longitude (`j`) along one latitude (`i`), so it should be returning one number. `u_zavg[i]` SHOULD be the mean of all those values, but it is currently receiving a vector because of the : (at least, that's my assumption). Any ideas to remedy this?

Comment: If you don't explain what your code was supposed to do, we can't tell you how to make your code do that.

Comment: What were you trying to make your code do when you wrote `u_zavg[i] = psum/len(lon)`?

Answer (score 0):

The full error message

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-25-aab34ac00f59>", line 11, in <module>
    u_zavg[i] = psum/len(lon)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Look at the values that are left (I'm using an interactive Ipython session):

```
In [36]: psum
Out[36]: array([], dtype=int64)
In [37]: lon
Out[37]: range(0, 180)
In [38]: len(lon)
Out[38]: 180
In [39]: psum/len(lon)
Out[39]: array([], dtype=float64)
In [42]: u_zavg.shape
Out[42]: (180,)
In [43]: u_zavg[i]
Out[43]: 0.0
```

You are trying to assign a (0,) shape array to a slot that expects one value.

While `psum` starts at `0`, you add something to it - a slice of `u10m`:

```
In [45]: u10m
Out[45]: array([], shape=(0, 180, 180), dtype=int64)
In [46]: len(time)
Out[46]: 0
In [47]: u10m[:,i,j]
Out[47]: array([], dtype=int64)
```

You start with `time` as `[]`, so `u10m` has a 0 dimension!

When constructing code like this, test, and test again.  Make sure you understand, and verify, each step.  Did you check the shape of `u10m`?

`len(lon)` isn't a usual construct, though it works ok, assuming that's what you want.

Comment: so for the original data, ```time``` is an "infinite" dimension (it can be appended to while lon and lat can't be), so it's just [ ] like how I have ```time``` here. did i misread your answer or is there something I can do for that?

Comment: `time` the list can be appended to.  But `u10m` as created has a 0 first dimension.  That's giving you a problem right away.  I'm focusing on what is happening, not what your wishes.

Comment: ah okay, how should I resolve ```u10m``` having a 0 first dimension?

Comment: Why does it even need an initial dimension,0,1, or `n`?  Why not just lat by lon?